# How to show emoji in angular/ionic app

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, utf-8

In my mobile app using angular5/ionic3 app I want to show emoji icon.

So I used something like

`<span>&#x1F601;</span>`

But in rendering it will show it as empty square.

I already have   `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my `index.html` and html file is also saved as utf-8.

I thought it could be related to sanitizing, so I created below pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(html) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}
```

and then I used it as

```
 <span [innerHTML]="'&#x1F601;' | safeHtml"></span>
```

but still result is the same

What did I miss?

[image]
[image]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nv12gKTXtI1ihmfYgTnx?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually happening when you don't have a font to display the character. On my computer Chrome uses the Symbola font to render this character. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/ChALkeR/Symbola-Emoji). Or you can find another font that supports emojis. Than you add the font in CSS using [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Symbola";
  src: url("/fonts/Symbola-Emoji.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/Symbola-Emoji.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Then you can use this font on a CSS `class`.

```css
.emoji {
    font-family: "Symbola"
}
```

Then you add that class to your `span`:

```
<span class="emoji">&#x1F601;</span>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you assign `&#x1F601;` to a variable and then read it inside the template it works fine:

```
<span [innerHTML]="someVariable | safeHtml"></span><!--this will work-->
```

But your code breaks: the `U+1F601` character (a.k.a. ) becomes [`U+F601`](https://unicode-table.com/en/F601/) and since you don't have a font to display it you get an empty square. It looks like a bug in Angular's template rendering engine because even if I do `<span [innerHTML]="(someVariable + '&#x1F601;') | safeHtml"></span>` it still breaks. I get the  and the `U+F601` character. So this is not the sanitizer problem.

Comment: I am not sure if it's related to font, I created a simple html file with same tag and it renders correctly, do you still suggest trying font?

Comment: _I created a simple html file with same tag and it renders correctly_ - Hmm... _do you still suggest trying font?_ - well tying this will not hurts :)

Comment: Is there a special reason you use HTML codes for emoji and not just put a `` character?

Comment: Good point, I just copy paste it and it's working, how can I copy paste the others?