# Angular - display emoji emoticons using html entities

Tags: angular, emoji, html-entities

Good morning,

I struggled to display an emoji with Angular in a component. Surprisingly it didn't work but it should. Please take a look on my basic test. Maybe you could clarify the issue.
I added example html tags to **index.html** and **app.component.html**. Below results.
I am wondering why it doesn't show emoji in the component...

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EmojiTest</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <h2>--- index.html below ---</h2>
  <div>
      &#128512; :grinning &#x1F609;
      ---- &#x263A; &#128514;
      &#x1F600; &#128512;
      <span>&#128517;</span>
      <span style='font-size:100px;'>&#128512;</span>
      <p>I will display &#128512;</p>
      <p>I will display &#x1F600;</p>
      
      HTML Entity (Decimal) &#9729;
      HTML Entity (Hexadecimal) &#x2601;
      ---
      &#x1f60d; &#xf556;
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Component**

```
<div>
  &#128512; :grinning &#x1F609;
  ---- &#x263A; &#128514;
  &#x1F600; &#128512;
  <span>&#128517;</span>
  <span style='font-size:100px;'>&#128512;</span>
  <p>I will display &#128512;</p>
  <p>I will display &#x1F600;</p>
  
  HTML Entity (Decimal) &#9729;
  HTML Entity (Hexadecimal) &#x2601;
  ---
  &#x1f60d; &#xf556;
</div>
```

Result:
[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqq3.png)

Comment: Check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052948/11823079) .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. It is not related to the font. When I create variable with the content as html entity,  it works fine in the component. Unfortunately I still cannot render emocji using html entity as a plain html tag. I can copy an emoji and paste - it works, html entity - doesn't. But anyway the link is very helpful and at least I know it will be working with variables and without any additional font! Still looking for the solution working for a plain html tag with html entity in component.